# Insert into makes new row for every value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with MySQL. I use PHP with mysqli to write data into prepared table. But if I submit the form, which values have to be written into table, each value makes new row in the table. Here is my code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["Field"]=array("Name1","Name2","Name3",...);
if(!empty($_POST)){
foreach($_SESSION["Field"] as $Variable){
if(!empty($_POST[$Variable])){
$_SESSION[$Variable]=$_POST[$Variable];
}}}
if(array_key_exists("Database",$Collection)){
$Database=mysqli_connect("localhost","dbadmin","password","mydatabase");
mysqli_query($Database,"insert into Table1 (PHPSESSID) values ('".session_id()."')");
foreach($_SESSION["Field"] as $Variable){
if(!empty($_POST[$Variable])){
$_SESSION[$Variable]=mysqli_real_escape_string($Database,$_SESSION[$Variable]);
mysqli_query($Database,"insert into Table1 ($Variable) values ('{$_SESSION[$Variable]}')");
}}
mysqli_close($Database);
}
```

**Update:** I think, that the problem is, because all variables should(?) be in one mysqli task. But I didn't find anything about it. Am I right? Should it be somethink like this `mysqli_query($Database,"insert into Table1 (Variable1,Variable2,Variable3) values ('Value1','Value2','Value3')");`?

**Update 2:** I think, that it could be also caused by not committing the insert tasks, but it isn't necessary to commit it, so I don't think, it is the problem. But I am a beginner in MySQL and SQL, so maybe I am wrong.

It both looks as a solution of my problem, but I don't know, how to make it in foreach loop with variables from an array. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to understand what [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) do before you try using them! Use the `foreach` loop to build the SQL query string, not commit to the database. After the loop has finished, you will have a complete SQL query that you can execute.

EDIT: Forgot the obligatory "Don't forget to escape your values before inserting them into the database!"

EDIT 2: Here's one answer. Certainly not elegant and not tested but could do the job:

```
session_start();
if(empty($_POST) || !array_key_exists("Database", $Collection)){
    exit;
}
$checklist = array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3");
$query = "INSERT INTO Table1 SET ";
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "dbadmin", "password", "mydatabase");

foreach($checklist as $v){
    if(!empty($_POST[$v])){
        $_SESSION[$v] = $_POST[$v];
        $_POST[$v] = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST[$v]);
        $query .= "$v='$_POST[$v]',"
    }
}

$query .= "PHPSESSID='" . session_id() . "'";

mysqli_query($db, $query);
mysqli_close($db);
```

Comment: I am beginner and I don't understand the first part of your answer at all. The two foreach loops could not be together, because they are on the other place in my code. In edit, if you mean mysqli_real_escape_string, than you're right, I forgot to write it here.

Comment: Could you add some small advice, where the problem is? Or small code example?

Comment: It seems to be workable. I'll try it and I'll report on the result ;-)

Comment: It works well! Thank you :-) But there is one another bug with encoding (or escaping maybe). I'll make a new question for it...